# When should you worry about interference affecting the analog input?

Tags: esp8266, analogread, wireless

I made something that uploads the measured current to Thingspeak. Everything works, but i did not place the DC to DC converter on the board because i was worried that it would interfere with the analog input. Also the ESP8266 is very close to the Arduino Pro Mini. Could it affect the reading?
Could i have put the DC to DC converter on the board without any problem?

[image: Arduino Pro Mini that uploads the current consumption to Thingspeak every 15 seconds]

230VAC to 12VDC adapter(not on the picture) --> 12VDC to 3,3VDC(on the picture)-->the prototype board

Sensor: SCT-013-030 30A = 1V

Comment: There is not enough information for making  hardware improvement suggestions.  For starters what are you using as a sensor?  What type of impedance does it have? Is it generating current, voltage or does its resistance vary? However, my first thought is to shorten what appears to be an excessively long cable between the ADC input and the sensor. And if you are really worried about power noise, try a test where you run everything off of batteries.

Comment: Sensor: SCT-013-030 30A = 1V

Comment: Ah, that's what that blue thing is!  The internal resistance is low.  About 62 ohms according to the specifications.  In general, the lower the internal resistance the less influence electrical noise will make.   We can say it is less likely for the switcher to interfere with the ADC should you decide to mount it on the board.  I am a bit more concerned about the switcher coupling with the radio.  To be safe, I would keep them on opposite sides of the board and point the radio's antenna away from the switcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are more likely to have noise injected on the power pins of the Arduino that by EMI or capacitative coupling. With the switcher on board of off board it will make no difference if the voltage it supplies to the Arduino (and hence to the ADC) is noisy and full of spikes.

Answer (score 0):

Noise reduction involving Analog to Digital Conversions can be done in many ways.  Common software solutions involve averaging multiple conversions.  [Exponential smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing) is one such method.  One advantage of exponential smoothing is that it can be applied to an endless stream of conversions.

Comment: I don't want to smooth it, i just want to know if the DC to DC converter or the ESP8266 could affect the analog reading?
Also the analog input is an AC signal, i guess you can't smooth that.

Comment: Actually ADC are noisy enough that, say, an 8 bit ADC only gives you a few bits of significant accuracy w/o taking multiple samples into consideration.  The DC to DC is probably operating at a high frequency.  So, guessing because I don't know much about your sensor, you might be able to mitigate any effect by adding a low pass filter to the ADC input.  In the end, designing with switchers is notoriously problematic.  I have seen hardware designers spinning boards because of switcher problems.  Others may have more experience, but this may come down to trying & testing.